How can I manipulate an autocomplete text field exposed form filter to be a select list?
I have been trying to just use a form alter hook with code like this
if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-my-form') {

    $nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
      ->accessCheck(FALSE)
      ->condition('type','article')
      ->execute();
        $nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
        $options = ['' => t('- Any -')];

        foreach($nodes as $nid => $node) {
            $value = $node->getOwner()->label();
      $id = $node->getOwner()->id();

            if (isset($value)) {
                $options[$id] = $value;
            }
        }

        if (isset($form['uid'])) {
      $form['uid'] = [];
            $form['uid']['#type'] = 'select';
            $form['uid']['#options'] = $options;
            $form['uid']['#size'] = '';
        }
    }

but, in the end the option value gets processed in the InOperator class and ultimately errors in the opSimple method because $this->value being passed to array_values is a string. I've tried lots of approaches in my form alter hook to get this right, but I think I'm doing something more fundamentally wrong, since it's not clear to me why this filter class is processing the value.
